# Mysql query not fetching data by order

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch data using left join.My table's are something like below :

Table 1 :

```
========================
     id   |   name
========================
      1   |   Amit
========================
      2   |   Manzoor
========================
      3   |   Atik
========================
      4   |   Sharif
```

Table 2 :

```
===========================================
  t2_id  |    Date    | table1_id  |   status
===========================================
   1  | 2014-03-03 |   1        |   1
===========================================
   2  | 2014-03-04 |   2        |   1
===========================================
   3  | 2014-03-05 |   3        |  1
```

My query is given below :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t1.table1_id ORDER BY status DESC
```

If today's date will match with above's table2 date than I need my data something like below

```
  id   |    name   |    t2_id     |    date    | table1_id  |   status
======================================================================
   1   |   Amit    |     1        | 2014-03-03 |   1        |   1
======================================================================
   2   |   Manzoor |     2        | 2014-03-04 |   2        |   1
======================================================================
   3   |   Atik    |     3        | 2014-03-05 |   3        |   1 
======================================================================
    4   |   Sharif |     NULL     | NULL       |   NULL     |  NULL
```

Any Idea?

Comment: "something like below"? man, you cannot even put it into words?

Comment: It looks like there's a mistake in your query. Did you mean `...ON t1.id=t2.table1_id ORDER BY...`? You referred to t1.table1_id but it's really t2.table1_id.

Comment: You want to select date < today's date?

Comment: No, I want to select everything but I want to view my result like above.If you have date like -2014-03-05,2014-03-06,2014-03-02,I need to show if in the order like -2014-03-02,2014-03-05,2014-03-06

Comment: so how do you order the record? by date? by status? or what?

Comment: he doesn't know. vote to close.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: He is trying to order by the date field. So when date is null, it comes first. And he does not want that to come first in the order.

Comment: @RagingBull: there are several ways to interpret his example, so that's just *guessing*. I want to hear it from him.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: He has commented it at Andrew's answer.

Comment: Still, not a full description.

Comment: Yes, I want to sort by date and status desending order.But with one condition,if date is match with current,it will show first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN 
table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.table1_id 
WHERE t2.Date IS NOT NULL
AND t2.Date = curdate()
ORDER BY t2.status DESC) T1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN 
table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.table1_id 
WHERE t2.Date IS NOT NULL 
      AND t2.Date <> curdate()
ORDER BY t2.Date ASC, t2.status DESC) T

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN 
table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.table1_id 
WHERE t2.Date IS NULL
```

**Explanation:**

It will select all records if `date` field is `not null` and current date in order of status

UNION with records if `date` field is `not null` and **not** current date  in order of `date`.

UNION with the records in which `date` field is `null`.

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/daf603/22).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think It will work for me. I will try it now, after that I will mark this answer

Comment: @CrazyMan: Sure, my friend. Let me know if you need further modification to your result.

Comment: Its working,but I need to display it by one condition.If date is match with current date, it will show first.How can I do this?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26259/1 here is my new fiddle link.You will see first two rows.Name amit,atik.I need to show atik first because today is 2014-03-04.I hope you understand.

Comment: @CrazyMan: See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26259/4). Changed the order by clause in the second query.

Comment: Sorry,miscommunication.I need name atik which status is 1.

Comment: How? his date is march 4?

Comment: @CrazyMan: There are two order by in second query. change their position to first or second. And their order asc to desc and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
ORDER BY status IS NULL, status DESC
```

this statement `status IS NULL` will return 1 for true and 0 for false, so ordering it by ascending makes `NON-NULL` first in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You should `ORDER BY id` if you want it sorted as shown. You could sort by multiple columns if you want it to sort by id and then sort by status: `ORDER BY id, status`.

If you'd like to sort by date but place the NULL values at the bottom then: `ORDER BY date IS NULL, date`

Comment: If I sort by id,status its not showing proper result for NULL values

Comment: Do you mean that the NULL values show up in the wrong order? Or they don't show up at all?

Comment: NULL value showing wrong order.If I place Desc order, NULL value displaying first in the table

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this!